# Selenium in Python - The download dialogue still opens

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have applied all the configurations to prevent the download window pop-up, but still comes up, even in Option in FF, the config is set to "save file to". It drives me crazy, please help:

```
    profile = webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile.FirefoxProfile()

    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2) # custom location
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", path)
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', ('text/tsv'))
    profile.set_preference("webdriver_enable_native_events", False)

    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.scanWhenDone",False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.useWindow",False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force",False)
    #profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', os.getcwd())   

'text/plain, application/vnd.ms-excel, text/tsv, text/comma-separated-values, application/octet-stream, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')

    profile.update_preferences()   

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
    driver.implicitly_wait(60)
    base_url ="the base url"
```

Comment: Why have I got -1 on this question?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/force-download")
```

In any case, the following works for me:

```
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)

profile..set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/force-download")
profile..set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", True)
```

Comment: It does't work for me. Even the download directory can be set from set_preference, but the download windows still appears. I feel either  driver.implicitly_wait(60) brings the problem or  the tsv format of the file for download. Because it works on other download operations on my computer, except of this one. BTW thanks

Answer (score 0):

For FireFox version 91.3.0esr I used:

```
self.profile.set_preference(
            "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
            "text/tab-separated-values")
```

My other Firefox profile setting are the same as OP:

```
self.profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
self.profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
self.profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", Path)
```

So, for a tsv I am using: 'text/tab-separated-values'

I got this from the FireFox Debug tool for the network> I just opened the Debuger F-12, and clicked on the Network tab. Then just clicked on the file download link and the details for the file transfer are in the Response Header: Content-Type.